# What Statistical Analysis test do I run for Pre/post test?

Tags: anova, t-test, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test, mcnemar-test

Hello I am conducting a study where I examine patients who have not received a flu vaccination. In all I have 45 participants all who have not received the vaccine. I implemented and educational pamphlet in hopes this would change their mind for the current flu season. I also distributed a quiz prior to and after education to test their knowledge. What tests do I run to examine their scores and rates of vaccination pre/post education?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you can draw any conclusions from this study. What is your null hypothesis? No one can unvaccinate themselves, so if one person gets a vaccination, what does that mean?

Comment: There is no pre for vaccinations, only post. So just report what % were vaccinated.  But for knowledge score, try a paired samples t-test or Wilcoxon signed rank test.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I did a chart review of 45 people that did not get the vaccination last year (pre educational vaccine rate. After providing education to them I wanted to see if that it would changer their mind and get vaccinated this flu season.